# Webscraping of news articles on press reader

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

What I have to do for my job is to do a webscraping of some news articles of the newspaper "Libero" on the website Pressreader [Link](https://www.pressreader.com/italy/libero) by using some keywords in a precise period of time. After that, I should store them on a .csv file.

I have talked with a colleague of mine and he suggested me to use the following R packages: rvest, Rselenium and httr. Additionally, he also suggested me to have a look at this page for having an idea of what to do.

However, the structure of the website (the way the articles are showed) is pretty unusual and I am having a lot of problems in even conceiving the code that I could use...
I have looked everywhere on the internet, asked on ChatGPT and so on, but I haven't find a source that can actually be helpful.

I hope that someone of you will be able to help me. Thanks a lot to everyone in advance.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Can you provide the code that you have tried?